# django rest framework comment form not sending data (how to send and recieve json data using angular js)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I originally used following `ajax` call to send the `POST` data to the `django rest framework` API.

```
$('#comment_form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault()

  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: '/api/comments/create/',
    headers:{ 'X-CSRF-Token': getCookie('csrftoken') },
    data:$('#post_form').serialize(),
    error: function(response){
      alert('Not authorized.');  // Or something in a message DIV
    },
    success: function(response){
    // do something with response
 }
 });

});
```

but for some reason, I was getting `404` error when i try to `POST` anything using the comment `form`,
when rest of the other forms such as login `form` and `POST` `form` work just fine.

(here is the live site that contains that comment box http://192.241.153.25:8000/#/post/images2)

i figured it's because it's added later to the `DOM` by using angualr js's routing function.

it throws me the typical `csrf` token missing error when the console network tab sends `csrf` properly.

does anyone know any solution to this problem?

i wonder if it works fine if i use `AngularJs` instead of `jQuery` `ajax`.

Comment: There are many issues that I can think of. First, missing CSRF should not give you a 404. Second, jquery's document ready is not called again when angular changes the template. You need either to call the jquery function manually at the end of the controller or add a relevant event. Third, this would not have posted at all and not give you a 404, which seems very odd. So you need to investigate your code further. I would strongly recommend you, since you're using angular, not to use jquery's ajax and use angular's http or service instead.

Answer (score 1):

As I see on your current page there is 403 error, caused by csrf protection check.

Set csrf cookie name in your angularjs `config()` function according to django's values https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax

```
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
```